Failed to load system plugin [libwind_plugin.so] : couldn't find shared library
I am trying to launch a file from a codebase in github. I am getting the error as follows
[Err] [SystemLoader.cc:94] Failed to load system plugin [libwind_plugin.so] : couldn't find shared    library.
I cloned the repo from scratch several times and installed gazebo plugins too.
